# How would I split a string into first name, preferred name, and last name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The standard string would be "First (Pref) Last" but some have different formats, such as one without preferred names "First Last". Others have two first names "First First (Pref) Last", and one is missing a space between a parentheses and the last name "First (Pref)Last". i understand how to do First (Pref) Last and First Last but the last two examples trip up my query. Here is my code for the first two.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[NameTester]
SET FName = PARSENAME(REPLACE(FullName,' ','.'),3),
    PrefName = PARSENAME(REPLACE(FullName,' ','.'),2),
    LName = PARSENAME(REPLACE(Fullname,' ','.'),1)
where FullName like '% % %'


UPDATE [dbo].[NameTester]
SET FName = PARSENAME(REPLACE(FullName,' ','.'),2),
    LName = PARSENAME(REPLACE(Fullname,' ','.'),1)
where FullName not like '% % %'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you don't use `parsename()`.  Instead, do the breaks on the parens.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[NameTester]
    SET FName = TRIM(LEFT(FullName, charindex('(', FullName) - 1)),
        PrefName = SUBSTRING(LEFT(FullName, charindex(')', FullName) - 1), charindex('(', FullName) + 1, len(FullName)), 
        LName = TRIM(RIGHT(FullName, charindex(')', reverse(FullName)) - 1))
    where FullName like '%(%)%';
```

Here is an example using a `select` (which is also on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/41073)):

```
select trim(LEFT(FullName, charindex('(', FullName) - 1)),
       SUBSTRING(LEFT(FullName, charindex(')', FullName) - 1), charindex('(', FullName) + 1, len(FullName)), 
       trim(RIGHT(FullName, charindex(')', reverse(FullName)) - 1))
from (select 'a (b) c' as fullname union all
      select 'abc (def)ghi' union all
      select 'abc def (ghijkl) kkk'
     ) t
```